# Transform translating a JavaFX Line

Tags: javafx, line, translation

So I have a displayed Line, which I now want to move to a new locations by animation. TranslateTransition only uses one pair of X and Y coordinates, whereas a Line has two sets of coordinates, one for the start and one for the end of the Line. Is there anyway to specify a TranslateTransition for a Line?

I know about binding a Line (which I can't easily figure out how to apply in my case), but is there a general TranslateTransition solution I can apply to a Line (I know the new start and end coordinates where I want the Line to move to .. so this might be the easiest way, if there is a way ...)

Comment: A [`Timeline`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) allows for animating arbitrary `WritableValue`s.

Comment: As of JavaFX 12 there doesn't seem to be a `TransformTranslation` in the standard API. Where did you get that class from?

Comment: fabian, apologies : I meant TranslateTranslation .. will go back and edit my question.

Comment: Looking at a binding approach I've seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879382/javafx-8-drawing-a-line-between-translated-nodes : uses Circle. I can't figure out how to make it work for Rectangle.

Comment: Just to say thanks for the help. I should've provided sample code, I was lazy, and I apologise. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to use `TranslateTransition` using a `Line`.

```
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Line line = new Line(10, 10, 10, 40);        
        TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(6),line);
        translateTransition.setFromX(10);
        translateTransition.setToX(380);
        translateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        translateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);        

        Line line1 = new Line(10, 60, 10, 90);
        Line line2 = new Line(10, 60, 40, 60);
        Line line3 = new Line(40, 60, 40, 90);
        Line line4 = new Line(10, 90, 40, 90);
        Group group = new Group(line1, line2, line3, line4);
        TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(6),group);
        translateTransition2.setFromX(10);
        translateTransition2.setToX(380);
        translateTransition2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        translateTransition2.setAutoReverse(true);        

        ParallelTransition parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition(translateTransition, translateTransition2);
        parallelTransition.play();

        Pane root = new Pane(line, group);
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);


        // Show the stage

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableColumnGrow Sample");
        primaryStage.show();


    }
}
```

**Updated Code: I added a `Group` to the example.**